# MariaDB, Convert VARCHAR to DECIMAL

Tags: mariadb, decimal, varchar

I have a column with VARCHAR i i want convert to DECIMAL for use after in a query in my vb project. But i don't find the correct syntax.

I try fisrt like mysql use :

```
SELECT 
CAST(REPLACE(Espesor,',','.') AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS TT
FROM Produccion
WHERE id = 153392
```

and i have 5,5 (Works fine).
But under MariaDB i the syntax is different. Is like this

```
DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
```

I Tried with the follow code :

```
SELECT 
CAST(REPLACE(Espesor,',','.') AS DECIMAL[(10[,2])]) AS TT
FROM Produccion
WHERE id = 153392
```

and i have an error near [(10[,2])]) AS TT

Comment: The syntax isn't different, and I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's finaly a problem with Visual Studio 2015 and my MYSQL updates.
I uninstall :

1. Mysql for Visual Studio 1.2.8
2. Mysql Connector Net 8.0.16

And install :

1. Mysql for Visual Studio 2.0.5 m4
2. Mysql Connector Net 6.9.9

And all works again.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MariaDB SQL syntax is not different, it is just the documentation syntax that is.

Both MySQL and MariaDB allow to declare a column as `DECIMAL` without the parentheses, in that case default values are used for maximum number of digits, and number of decimals.

So `DECIMAL` is the same as `DECIMAL(10,0)`.

The MariaDB documentation is just more formal about describing this, using EBNF syntax, where the square brackets are used to show that the enclosed parts are optional.

So `DECIMAL[(M[,D])]` is actually saying that the '(...)' part is optional, and furthermore that the ',D' part also is. So

```
DECIMAL
DECIMAL(10)
DECIMAL(10,0)
```

are all valid variants, and all work the same with MySQL and MariaDB.

Just use your MySQL code unchanged on MariaDB, and it will work just fine there.

Comment: Ok. But when i generate a tableadapter un vb i have errors.
Error in function argument list: 'AS' is not recognized.
Error in the list of function arguments: ')' is not recognized.
Unable to parse the text of the query.

Comment: and generate like this :```SELECT        CAST(`REPLACE`(Espesor, ',', '.') AS `DECIMAL`(10, 2)) AS tt
FROM            Produccion
WHERE        id = 153392```

Comment: Why did you put the REPLACE function name and the DECIMAL type declarator in backticks? Backtics are the escape enclosure for table names. If at all, you want to put `Espesor`, `tt`, `Produccion` and `id` in backticks. (Although it is redundant here, as none of these column and table names are reserved words, or do contain special characters that require escaping).

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(Espesor, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS tt FROM Produccion WHERE id = 153392;